# Nested dictionaries Swift curly braces?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to create a nested dictionary in Swift, so I can change it to JSON later. I am setting it up like this:

```
let item: [String: AnyObject] = [
        "item": item,
        "price": price,
        "date": date,
        "time": time,
        "location": [
          "store": "Store name",
          "address": "1234 Untitled Dr.",
          "city": "City",
          "state": "CA",
          "zip": "12345"
        ]
      ]
print(item)
```

When I run this, the output is this:

```
["price": 15.69, "location": {
    address = "12350 Carmel MT Road";
    city = "City";
    state = CA;
    store = "Store name";
    zip = 12345;
}, "item": item, "date": , "time": ]
```

The location value is supposed to be a nested dictionary. Why are there curly braces surrounding the location part? And why are values inconsistent in whether there are quotes? Furthermore, when I try to access:

```
print(items["location"]!["store"])
```

I am told I:

> Cannot subscript a value of type `[[String : AnyObject]]' with an
>   index of type 'String'

Comment: Dictionaries are structs,  you need to do [String:Any] I think

Comment: You can't subscript `[[String:AnyObject]]` because that's an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Try printing: ```print((item["location"] as? [String: AnyObject])?["store"])```

Comment: Looks like you're accessing `items` which is an array, not `item`. Take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**:
Use `[String: Any]` instead of `[String: AnyObject]`.

**Longer answer:**:
The thing is Foundation automatically bridges Swift core types to Cocoa. This being said Swift `Dictionary` is being automatically bridged to `NSDictionary` because of the `AnyObject` constraint, a Swift struct can't be casted to an `AnyObject` and `Dictionary` is a struct.

The `print` function calls `description` property, which for `NSDictionary`s is with curly braces.

When specifying `Any` instead of `AnyObject` Swift will just set the variable type to Dictionary which has the square brackets `description`.

P.S.
About the `subscript` thing, I think you have an array there, so you should use something like `items[0]["location"]!["store"]`.

Comment: Makes sense! Also, thanks for the P.S., I totally forgot about that. Should have named my array better.